# Array issue with echoing the resutls

Tags: php, arrays

This is my parsed array. I parse some elements and placed them into my array `$results`. I think i am somewhere wrong cause i want to echo everything speacially the array `[display]` but i can't

```
Array
(
[Forologiki_Periodos] => 1ος Μήνας 2020
[Hmerologiaki_periodos] => 01/01/2020 - 31/01/2020
[Katastasi_ypoxrewsis] => Έχουν Υποβληθεί Δηλώσεις
[Hmerologiaki_periodos_apo] => 01/01/2020
[Hmerologiaki_periodos_ews] => 31/01/2020
[display] => Array
    (
        [0] => doDisplayDeclarationsList(document.displayDeclarationsListForm
        [1] => vatF2
        [2] => 2020
        [3] => oneMonth
        [4] => 01/01/2020
        [5] => 31/01/2020
        [6] => 01/01/2020
        [7] => 31/01/2020
    )

)
Array
(
[Forologiki_Periodos] => 2ος Μήνας 2020
[Hmerologiaki_periodos] => 01/02/2020 - 29/02/2020
[Katastasi_ypoxrewsis] => Έχουν Υποβληθεί Δηλώσεις
[Hmerologiaki_periodos_apo] => 01/02/2020
[Hmerologiaki_periodos_ews] => 29/02/2020
[display] => Array
    (
        [0] => doDisplayDeclarationsList(document.displayDeclarationsListForm
        [1] => vatF2
        [2] => 2020
        [3] => oneMonth
        [4] => 01/02/2020
        [5] => 29/02/2020
        [6] => 01/02/2020
        [7] => 29/02/2020
    )

)
Array
(
[Forologiki_Periodos] => 3ος Μήνας 2020
[Hmerologiaki_periodos] => 01/03/2020 - 31/03/2020
[Katastasi_ypoxrewsis] => Έχουν Υποβληθεί Δηλώσεις
[Hmerologiaki_periodos_apo] => 01/03/2020
[Hmerologiaki_periodos_ews] => 31/03/2020
[display] => Array
    (
        [0] => doDisplayDeclarationsList(document.displayDeclarationsListForm
        [1] => vatF2
        [2] => 2020
        [3] => oneMonth
        [4] => 01/03/2020
        [5] => 31/03/2020
        [6] => 01/03/2020
        [7] => 31/03/2020
    )

)
```

---

```
foreach ($result as $value){
    echo $value;
}
```

With this foreach i echo only the last element of $value, it should be echo all the 12 values. Also how can i get into the array `[display]` and echo values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop directy on the display as

```
foreach ($result['display'] as $display) {
    echo $display . '<br>';
}
```

But you can imbricate 2 loops

```
foreach ($result as $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $display) {
            echo '----' . $display . '<br>';
        }
    } else {
        echo $value . '<br>';
    }
}
```

The best solution is to use a function:

```
function displayArray($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $each) {
        if (is_array($each)) {
            displayArray($each);
        }

        echo $each . '<br>';
    }
}
```

So you can call the function like this:

```
displayArray($result);
```

Comment: It is correct, i am echoing all the results from the array but i am also getting an error `Array to string conversion` in  line which u have the last `echo $value . '<br>';` This happens When i am using the second choice that you wrote (But you can imbricate 2 loops

Comment: Yes you are right. I missed the else block. I just updated it.

Comment: i can't believe i missed that to. Thank you very much it works and i accepted your answer. Also pleace add one more `)` to your `if (is_array($value)` at the end.

Comment: hi again can you also tell me how to echo all the results because with this foreach i am getting only the lastone . For example `[Forologiki_Periodos] => 3ος Μήνας 2020` , `[Hmerologiaki_periodos] => 01/03/2020 - 31/03/2020` etc..  I want to echo everything

Comment: Hi @markos, These imbricated foreach are supposed to echo everything. Can you give more details? But the best solution is to use a function. I am going to edit my answer to add a function solution

Comment: I find my mistake thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Pls try this:

```
foreach (@$result['display'] as $key=>$value){
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: it works it's the same think like @spzout